# C++ opencv filter2d more than 3x slower than MATLAB conv2

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to reimplement an algorithm from matlab, which uses convolution, however when testing the speed of an equivalent algorithm in opencv, I noticed that opencv's filter2d is more than 3-4x slower than matlab's conv2. What is going on? I am running the C++ using visual  studio 2022

**C++:**

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <numeric>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    std::string image_path = samples::findFile("Starry_Night.jpg");
    Mat img = imread(image_path, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    if (img.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Could not read the image: " << image_path << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Mat kernelH(1, 3, CV_32F);
    kernelH.at<float>(0, 0) = 1.0f;
    kernelH.at<float>(0, 1) = 0.0f;
    kernelH.at<float>(0, 2) = -1.0f;

    Mat x_derivative;

    std::array<float,1000> times = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        filter2D(img, x_derivative, -1, kernelH, Point(-1, -1), 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        times[i] = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds> (end - begin).count();
    }

    double average = std::accumulate(times.begin(), times.end(), 0.0) / times.size();

    std::cout << average;

    imshow("Display window", x_derivative);
    int k = waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    if (k == 's')
    {
        imwrite("starry_night.png", img);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**MATLAB:**

```
img = rgb2gray(imread("Starry_Night.jpg"));

kernel = [-1 0 1];
times = zeros(1000,1);

for i = 1:1000
    
    tic
    der = conv2(img, kernel);
    times(i) = toc;
    
end

mean(times)*1000
```

Comment: Are you testing in Release mode? I have seen cases in Visual Studio where the Debug version took 100 times longer then Release for the same data and code.

Comment: Also, MATLAB is really, really optimized. They charge a ton of money for their license, and one of the reasons is because MATLAB is really really fast. I don't know about openCV, but I can assure you MATLAB is using multi-threading and highly optimized operations for it. There may be some issue in your code, but I do not think you will be able to be _faster_ than MATLAB

Comment: I understand that, but for such a trivial algorithm like a convolution, this level of slowdown seems extremely large

Comment: @MattCaius I contest the "trivial" part. A fast Fourier transform that is really properly optimized its not trivial, or people would not be able to sell libraries that do it. MATLAB is really fast _specifically_ in these things. Matrix multiplications, ffts, etc.

Comment: OpenCV does use all kinds of parallelization and math libraries (intel MKL, ...) if available. docs say that `filter2D` is DFT-based, if the kernel is large enough! for small kernels, direct calculation is cheaper. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04

Comment: OpenCV is all about speed, if you believe their mission statement, but a lot of their algorithms are not at all optimal. For example, PocketFFT, which has a compatible license, is significantly faster than OpenCV's FFT implementation, even for "nice" sizes; for other sizes, the difference is orders of magnitude! It would be so simple for OpenCV to use switch out their implementation for PocketFFT... There are other examples too: DIPlib's Gaussian filter is faster than OpenCV's by a good margin, even though DIPlib is written to prioritize precision whereas OpenCV is written to prioritize speed.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Can you recommend a very fast direct convolution function? Ideally, it would be around or better than the Matlab implementation.

Comment: As @drescherjm suggested in the first comment, can you tell us what optimization level you're compiling with?

Comment: @beaker Release x64

Comment: Can you show getBuildInformation? Are you using avx2 optimizations etc.? Is there a chance that Matlab automatically uses GPU support? That's a Sobel kernel, right? Can you try opencv's sobel function? Maybe that's more optimized? Not sure whether 1D kernel has an optimized  processing strategy, that is automatically selected by matlab.

Comment: Not sure whether sepFilter2D() is another option

Comment: You can probably gain some time by writing a specific function to apply this particular filter. OpenCV multiplies values by -1, 0 and 1, then adds them up. You can simply subtract two values instead, saving 3 multiplications and 1 addition. If you don't care about the boundary pixels, keep those at 0 in the output and you save all the effort needed to do proper boundary conditions too. This is the best way to obtain optimally efficient code: don't make the code generic.

Comment: usually C and C++ get the upper hands compared to MATLAB when you are pushing on speed. consider writing you own CUDA/OpenCL convolution code. it should beat MATLAB by a big margin on a decent GPU. Even a multi-threaded version (OpenMP for example) can also easily be faster than MATLAB.

Comment: @CrisLuengo This is not specific to the sobel filter - would you recommend implementing a bespoke algorithm for every kernel I will use. I don't super care about how much work it is because I need to get the convolutions as fast as humanly possible for this algorithm to work

Comment: A bespoke piece of code can be much faster than a generic piece of code. In this case, the only way to make it faster than MATLAB's `conv` is to write a bespoke piece of code. As I explained above, a bespoke piece of code can do the same computation with less work because of the particular weights you're using.

Comment: @FangQ It very much depends on what you do. Convolution is highly optimized in MATLAB, as is, for example, matrix multiplication, matrix factorization, or solving linear systems of equations. And MATLAB uses all CPU cores for these operations by default. You would not be able to write code in C or C++ that comes close to matching the MATLAB implementations (and neither could I). Sure, using the GPU you could do better, but so can MATLAB! All you need to do is pay for the right toolbox to benefit from GPU computation within MATLAB.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I am not arguing MATLAB's convolution is not highly optimized - the question is how it is optimized, and how can you do better? Yes, you can "buy" whatever implementation that works for you, but if you know what to do, especially writing such a basic algorithm on the GPU, you can do it too, and much faster. You could even start with many free codes available, like [this one](https://github.com/debowin/cuda-tiled-2D-convolution) and [this one](https://github.com/krunal1313/2d-Convolution-CUDA). All you need is a `mexFunction()` that passes the pointers.